# Magento ReIndexing the Product Prices

Tags: magento, reindex

I have been dealing with this issue for a couple of days now, and just cant seem to pinpoint the problem, or more importantly an answer. I have tried the follow..

- Clearing the cache
- deleting var/locks
- reindexing through ssh
- truncating _flat tables
- database repair tool

I am open to anything at this point... any help or a link in the right direction would help greatly. Thanks.

```
Product Prices index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list doe
s not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
' in /home/blazerad/public_html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 /home/blazerad/public_html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDO
Statement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/blazerad/public_html/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(1
10): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/blazerad/public_html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_
Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/blazerad/public_html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479):
Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home/blazerad/public_html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(23
8): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sm...', Array)
#5 /home/blazerad/public_html/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419
): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sm...', Array)
#6 /home/blazerad/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resour
ce/Product/Indexer/Price/Default.php(287): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query
('INSERT INTO `sm...')
#7 /home/blazerad/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/R
esource/Indexer/Price.php(47): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Pr
ice_Default->_prepareFinalPriceData()
#8 /home/blazerad/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resour
ce/Product/Indexer/Price.php(385): Mage_Downloadable_Model_Resource_Indexer_P
rice->reindexAll()
#9 /home/blazerad/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/
Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindex
All()
#10 /home/blazerad/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process
.php(209): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#11 /home/blazerad/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process
.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#12 /home/blazerad/public_html/magento/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Mod
el_Process->reindexEverything()
#13 /home/blazerad/public_html/magento/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Com
piler->run()
#14 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[21S01]: I
nsert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match
value count at row 1' in /home/blazerad/public_html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/State
ment/Pdo.php:234
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 /home/blazerad/public_html/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(1
10): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/blazerad/public_html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_
Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/blazerad/public_html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479):
Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/blazerad/public_html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(23
8): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sm...', Array)
#4 /home/blazerad/public_html/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419
): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sm...', Array)
#5 /home/blazerad/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resour
ce/Product/Indexer/Price/Default.php(287): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query
('INSERT INTO `sm...')
#6 /home/blazerad/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/R
esource/Indexer/Price.php(47): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Pr
ice_Default->_prepareFinalPriceData()
#7 /home/blazerad/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resour
ce/Product/Indexer/Price.php(385): Mage_Downloadable_Model_Resource_Indexer_P
rice->reindexAll()
#8 /home/blazerad/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/
Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindex
All()
#9 /home/blazerad/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.
php(209): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#10 /home/blazerad/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process
.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#11 /home/blazerad/public_html/magento/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Mod
el_Process->reindexEverything()
#12 /home/blazerad/public_html/magento/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Com
piler->run()
#13 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should to check a query and table structure

Open file
    app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Default.php

And find line with

```
$query = $select->insertFromSelect($this->_getDefaultFinalPriceTable(), array(), false);
```

You may print variable $query and result of the function `$this->_getDefaultFinalPriceTable()`, you may do it when you call reindex from the console.

Comment: `$query = $select->insertFromSelect($this->_getDefaultFinalPriceTable(), array(), false);
        $write->query($query);`

I see this line, but i am unsure what your suggesting i change it to

Comment: Add after this line next code
`var_dump($query, $this->_getDefaultFinalPriceTable()); dd();`

and run `shell/indexer.php`

You will get sql query and table name after that you should check them

Comment: Hi, you should add `var_dump($query, $this->_getDefaultFinalPriceTable()); dd();` before `$write->query($query);`

Comment: Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home/blazerad/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Default.php on line 287

Comment: I got sql query and got field list from this query:
`entity_id, customer_group_id, website_id, tax_class_id, orig_price, price, min_price, max_price, tier_price, base_tier, group_price, base_group_price`.

Could you check table's structure for table 'catalog_product_index_price_final_idx'?

Comment: How I understand you use custom module which changed table's structure and could change a behaviour of indexer because field `store_id` is absent by default

Comment: www.blazerproducts.com/magento/this.jpg   i think i found where im having the issue... now to try and fix it...